# How long can I soak red kidney beans for?

Tags: food-safety, beans

I have had red kidney beans (dried) soaking for 2 days now as I didn't get around to cooking them yesterday. Will they still be safe to eat if I cook them up tonight? Thanks!

Comment: Yes for sure.  I've done this several times.  Make sure to change the water however

Answer (score 1):

Stir and watch for bubbles.

Beans tend to start fermenting after a day of soaking. It's not sure they will, but they often do. They will still be edible, if slightly sub-par if they just began, but a day more and you should toss them.
If you see the soaked beans to "fizzle" like carbonated drink, toss them. If they barely release a minimal amount of bubbles or none at all, cook them thoroughly and you're good. Also, if they start minimally fizzling, make sure to wash them thoroughly. Most of "spoilage" is in the water and on the surface.